# Sql query for like operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a search box where user enters anything in textbox and submits.Lets say user enters Peter.If we are comparing in sql table with following query

```
select * from xml where name like '%peter%'
```

This query works well,but when i want to search for only peter in the string,then it creates a problem.Like when i want to search for only those rows which are having Peter present in the name column.
in name column,value 1-My name is Peter.
valu2-My name is Peterwatter.
valu3-My name is Peter living in US.
when i want to search it should give only first and third row.not the second one.BUt with above query i m getting all the three rows.How can i correct that.Please guide on this

Comment: @Mihai why wouldn't this return the second one?

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from xml 
 where name like '%peter'
    or name like '%peter %'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do so with regular expressions, but a simple solutions can be like this:

```
[name] like '% peter %' 
or [name] like '% peter' 
or [name] like 'peter %' 
or [name] = 'peter'
```

Answer (score 0):

try `like '% peter %'`
(with spaces after/before the wild cards)
However please watch out for sql injections.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Would this not select all three values? Are you sure?

Comment: will this b prone to sql injection attacks sir.if we dont escape characters sir.

Comment: @Hituptony actually i have a mistake and it will only select row 3 since there is not a space after peter. Seems that coder's answer above is better.

Comment: @user3575612 this type of query is prone to sql injection because you are taking user input and passing it to the database. perhaps you can paramatize the query and turn it into a stored procedure.

Comment: actually coder is wrong as well he's trying to match all conditions, essentially he's taking the long way to do what you're doing.

Comment: @Hituptony i wrote this little query using a table variable to check his code (and mine, after your comment). and his code seems to produce the results that we are after....

`declare @table1 table  
(
testText varchar(255)
)

insert into @table1 values('My name is Peter')
insert into @table1 values('My name is Peterwatter')
insert into @table1 values('My name is Peter living in US')
 

select * from @table1 where testText  like '% peter %' 
or testText like '% peter' 
or testText like 'peter %' 
or testText = 'peter'`

Comment: There is a period after 'My name is Peter.'

Comment: remember he wants to exclude the second value, your answer will include it because it matches the initial white space before the Peterwatter

Comment: "because it matches the initial white space before the Peterwatter"...but it fails the white space after. it works for the second row but not the first for the same reasons. i fully admit my answer is wrong and if you add the period coder's answer above doesn't work either.

Comment: It's a LIKE operand, I'm pretty sure it will match either case. I agree the periods are somewhat misleading, no? I'm not trying to pick on you bro, just pointing out what i see :)

Comment: @b3ko-if i escapse the character before passing it to query,is it fine then  sir?

Comment: @Hituptony i know you are not picking on me ;) we are both just searching for the truth!
maybe this is the most complete:
` testText  like '% peter %' 
or testText like '% peter.%' 
or testText like 'peter %'
or testText like '% peter'`

this will match for peter as the first value with a space after it, the last value with a period after, or anywhere in the middle surrounded by spaces. also '% peter' to get the last value without a period.  ok back to work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from xml 
 or name like '%Peter.'
 or name like 'Peter%'
 or name like 'Peter %'
 or name like '% Peter.'
 or name like '% Peter %'
```

Edit:: Now it will.

Comment: Will this exclude the second value?  1-My name is Peter. valu2-My name is Peterwatter. valu3-My name